# A lot of DNS query from localhost for a proxy - Why?

Tags: bind

```
25-Jun-2013 15:31:57.138 queries: client 127.0.0.1#41134: query: 163.117.242.173.in-addr.arpa IN PTR + (127.0.0.1)
25-Jun-2013 15:31:57.150 queries: client 127.0.0.1#48114: query: proxy4.router.pm IN A + (127.0.0.1)
```

In my bind log, there a LOT of query like this. From localhost. But what is this !? 
What's on my server asking for reverse query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it is impossible to say what is causing these reverse lookups.

Such lookups are typically done by services listening on the network interface whenever somebody tries to connect. If this is the case here, you could e.g. use tcpdump to find what service is being used by this IP address: `tcpdump -n host <ip>`.

Comment: I disinstalled from server samba and win<something> an rebooted.
No more query .. boh !